# Load local JSON files via file:// triggers cross-domain null origin violation, solution? (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, cross-domain

I have a webpage I'd like to use locally, without a web server, by simply opening the local HTML file in my browser. This webpage in question loads data via jQuery's getJson() method, as in:

```
$.getJSON("mydata.json", function(j) { 
...
```

The JSON files are also local, and are stored in the same directory as the webpage. When I attempt to use the page, I get:

**Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.**

(Chrome 6 OS X, similar errors in Firefox and Safari).

Is there any way around this? Is it possible to load JSON from local files? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running Chrome with `--allow-file-access-from-files`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I get "unable to load file" when I try it that way.