# Why Json file content is not shown in html page?

Tags: javascript, json

I am quite new in javascript and I want to show the content of json file by using javascript. My problem is that the html page cannot show the content of Json file and it is blank!! I know I am fetching it correctly. I have this Json file on my local drive with name, data.json. I have also change the address of the file but it does not work.

Coul dyou tell me what the reason is? 
Thanks,

I put the code here

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>

<script>

    $(function() {


   var people = [];

   $.getJSON("home/Documents/data.json", function(data) {
       $.each(data.person, function(i, f) {
          var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.firstName + "</td>" +
           "<td>" + f.lastName + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.job + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.roll + "</td>" + "</tr>"
           $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
     });

   });

});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="profile">
   <table id= "userdata" border="2">
  <thead>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
            <th>City</th>
        </thead>
      <tbody>

       </tbody>
   </table>

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide the JSON in question

Comment: You're likely running into a Same Origin Policy problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851691/load-local-json-files-via-file-triggers-cross-domain-null-origin-violation-s

Answer (score 3):

> I have this Json file on my local drive

Don't try doing Ajax on a local disk, you'll run into browser security restrictions. Run a web server and do it over HTTP.

You should have got a clue about this by looking at the JavaScript Error Console in your browser's Developer Tools.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you tell me where I should put my Json file instead of local disk? I am not so familiar with Javascript.

Comment: The file should still exist on the local disk, it just should be access over HTTP. As I said *run a webserver*.